# The Twitter HTML Embed code isn't working completely

Tags: html, twitter, widget, embed

This is the code I have right now for the HTML twitter embed:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-width="280" data-height="440"
    data-theme="dark" data-link-color="#E81C4F" 
    data-chrome="noheader nofooter noborders transparent noscrollbar" 
    href="https://twitter.com/CodeLacuna?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">
    Tweets by CodeLacuna
</a> 
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I am using it for a site on wix. However, despite changing the code to have "noscrollbar", there is still a scroll bar! Which makes no sense. So I'm wondering if perhaps there is some sort of update with the coding that I need to take into account for? I can't do CSS as I am only limited to HTML.
Here is a screenshot of what the result of the code looks like The top and bottom borders are separate assets I added myself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not quite the same but might work for you...? Does adding this to the anchor tag still work these days (replace with your number)?

```
data-tweet-limit="2"
```